# Truth Table for the Following Multiplexer Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, boolean-algebra, decoder

Is the truth table (shown below) accurate for the decoder/multiplexer circuit (shown farther below)?

```
+-------------------+
| A | B | C | D | F |
+-------------------+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | N |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | P |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Q |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | R |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | s |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | T |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | U |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | V |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | W |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | X |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Z |
+-------------------+
```

The Circuit:
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Start reasoning 'out loud' about why you've shown those particular lines in your truth table, and we'll pitch in with whether those are valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yea. Correct.

You can also implement this using one large 16:1 MUX or two 8:1 MUX.

Or by replacing decoder with another 4:1 MUX.

Try all varieties.